# Java7u65/Java8u11 - %20 is illegal in any URL contained in the JNLP file?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have an application that worked perfectly fine with all of the Java 7 and Java 8 releases prior to the latest updates (Java7u65 and Java8u11).

The problem seems to be that I escape a space in the URL and replace it with "%20" which is the correct replacement for a space charater in a URL but Java Web Start is complaining about it and just removing the URL entirely from the parsed JNLP file.

For some reason the latest version of Java spits out the following message when parsing the JNLP file:

```
security: Rejecting argument with illegal chars: http://www.somewebitenamehere.net/path%20with%20spaces/
```

What could have changed in the latest update that is now causing this message?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.